# In Python word search, searching diagonally, printing result of where word starts and ends

Tags: python, search

I have a friend of mine tutoring me in learning Python and he gave me this project where a user will read a word search into the program and the file includes a list of words that will be in the word search. I have to search for these words and some of the words run diagonally. If I find the word, I must print in what row and what column (the coordinates) the word starts and the word ends. I've only been learning Python 2 weeks so I'm confused, how would I search for a word diagonally and get the starting point and ending point of a word? The sample word search is down below and the words to search are with it. I have worked through it and spent 3 days on it and nothing has come of it.

Word Search

```
HGAMONIHRA
AOMOKAWONS
NFROLBOBDN
ARFSIHCAGE
LNIEEWONOK
GOLFUNDTHC
KOCATAOHBI
AMRERCGANH
SLGFAMALLC
ALLIGATORX
```

Words to search

```
CAT
DOG
ALLIGATOR
CHICKEN
FROG
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#sting.find; https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html; (it's probably not helping you learn if you don't do it yourself)

Comment: Hey @Nelson2013, I'm sure people on here can answer, but you might find that you'll get more out of the exercise if you at least try it yourself first.  Maybe try the simplest (horizontal) case first.

Comment: If you've worked on it for three days, what have you produced?  What code or approaches have you tried?  Even if it hasn't worked, you'll learn from other people pointing out where you went wrong (and people will also be more inclined to help).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a brute force problem, however there are more efficient techniques available but keeping in mind that you are new to this field I won't suggest you to focus on algorithmic part, So first of all we will create a function called `search_diagonal` which will take 3 arguments as `starting_point`, `mesh`, `length_of_word` and you can do some pretty stuff inside that function depending upon the arguments passed.

One you have 3 arguments you can then easily propagate diagonally as:

```
MESH = ["HGAMONIHRA", "AOMOKAWONS", "NFROLBOBDN", "ARFSIHCAGE", 
"LNIEEWONOK", "GOLFUNDTHC", "KOCATAOHBI", "AMRERCGANH", "SLGFAMALLC", 
"ALLIGATORX"]

def search_diagonal(starting_point, MESH, length_of_word):
    new_word1 = ""
    new_word2 = ""
    new_word3 = ""
    new_word4 = ""
    for i in xrange(length_of_word):
        #Propagating in SE direction
        new_word1+=MESH[starting_point[0]+i][starting_point[1]+i]
    for i in xrange(length_of_word):
        #Propagating in NE direction
        new_word2+=MESH[starting_point[0]+i][starting_point[1]-i]
    for i in xrange(length_of_word):
        #Propagating in NW direction
        new_word3+=MESH[starting_point[0]-i][starting_point[1]-i]
    for i in xrange(length_of_word):
        #Propagating in SW direction
        new_word4+=MESH[starting_point[0]-i][starting_point[1]+i]
    return new_word1, new_word2, new_word3, new_word4
```

However there is a need to handle a lot of exception cases like index out of range etc. but this must give you a rough idea of how this problem can be solved.